# GitHub not letting to push after resetting keys triple times, based on their tutorial, based on bitbucket tutorial, still denied

Tags: github, ssh, git-remote

```
banana@banana-pc:~/Projects/bananaproject$ git remote add origin https://github.com/bananauser/bananaprojectmanager.git
error: remote origin already exists.
banana@banana-pc:~/Projects/bananaproject$ git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': ^C
banana@banana-pc:~/Projects/bananaproject$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi bananauser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
banana@banana-pc:~/Projects/bananaproject$
```

How can I be authenticated and not being able to push?

- I added my public key to my profile settings "SSH and GPG KEYS".
- I added my key to the ssh agent.
- I am authenticated based on `ssh -T git@github.com`
- I am just trying to initialise new repository and make a first push.

Note that on `ssh -T git@github.com` it also gives me correct github account name which is totally dissimilar to everything I have named on my pc.

JC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asked you to supply your username for `https://github.com` when pushing, so your remote was set to use HTTPS, `https://github.com/bananauser/bananaprojectmanager.git`, rather than what would be the SSH remote for that repository, `git@github.com:bananauser/bananaprojectmanager.git`.

It would have been possible to fix with;

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:bananauser/bananaprojectmanager.git
```

While the remote (see `git remote -v` to check it) was set to HTTPS, your SSH authentication wouldn't have mattered. Worth noting as well that verifying SSH authentication in that manner just verifies that the first successful try for a key that is set to be attempted for that host is an authenticated key for *some* user, not necessarily the owner of a repository, a detail which is important to keep in mind if you have multiple accounts and you're trying to verify a specific one, you need to make sure the key for that account it the first key it will attempt for `github.com`.

Comment: yes, you are correct. It would be nice if MSFT didn't add malignant instructions into empty prj tutorial. If they disabled the username anyway this year, then what's the point of keeping old instruction URL in README to init repo which wastes everyone time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by cloning empty project from GitHub and moving the content of my project to this cloned directory. Why github is breaking my nerves with project init is beyond infuriating as anything to do with MSFT.

So my authentication was fine.